# Update my gradle dependencies in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, gradle

I have a simple gradle project in my eclipse. I update the build.gradle to include a few apache http jars...

```
dependencies {
    compile group: 'commons-collections', name: 'commons-collections', version: '3.2'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.2.3'
    compile "org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.2.3"
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.+'
}
```

However in my code, where I reference some Apache HTTP stuff I get:

```
The import org.apache.http cannot be resolved
```

Any tips on what I need to do to make Eclipse see the new dependencies in my build.gradle?

I tried doing a clean but that does not work. My gradle plugin is:

```
  Gradle IDE    3.3.0.201307040643-RELEASE  org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.feature.feature.group   GoPivotal, Inc.
```

Answer (score 196):

You have to select "Refresh Dependencies" in the "Gradle" context menu that appears when you right-click the project in the Package Explorer.

Comment: Since this moment I started loving Gradle!

Comment: Great little sub-menu: the "Gradle (STS)" plugin should probably have made it into an Eclipse main menu (if this is possible)... Ctrl-F5 refreshes all...

Comment: In the project context menu, I had to click **Add Gradle Nature** under **Configure >** before the **Gradle** option appeared.

Comment: for me gradle only gives the option "refresh gradle project". But this may also be due to the error in eclipse "Invalid Gradle project configuration file: .settings/org.eclipse.buildship.core.prefs"

Comment: This solution has a bug. Every time I perform the refresh, the JRE is also [unnecessarily] changed to another one I don't want.

Comment: I only see Refresh Gradle Project as the only option under the gradle submenu when right clicking a project within eclipse

Comment: Do you know what does this do in the background? Is it actually executing `gradle clean` and then `gradle eclipse`? Or any other commands?

Comment: For me it was same situation as in the question, i simply was executing gradle clean and gradle build in STS run configuration, but after giving the eclipse task (gradle eclipse), the unresolved errors are gone

Answer (score 86):

Follow those steps to update Gradle project in Eclipse:

1. First, please check you have include eclipse gradle plugin. `apply plugin : 'eclipse'`
2. Then go to your project directory in Terminal. Type `gradle clean` and then `gradle eclipse`.
3. Then go to project in eclipse and refresh the project (Go to Project Explorer, select root of the project and hit F5 to refresh, or right click and select refresh in context menu).

[image]

Comment: I found this less effort than trying to get the Buildship Gradle plugin working in Eclipse.

Comment: Executing these allowed me to see that there was actually a problem. In my case, I saw `Could not resolve: org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.4`

Comment: In my case... I removed an dependence, and after, included the same dependence. But eclipse doesn't download again. To solve, I also had to perform "gradle eclipse" on command line.

Answer (score 29):

Looking at the [Eclipse plugin docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/eclipse_plugin.html#N170BC) I found some useful tasks that rebuilt my classpath and updated the required dependencies.

- First try `gradle cleanEclipse` to clean the Eclipse configuration completely. If this doesn;t work you may try more specific tasks:

  - `gradle cleanEclipseProject` to remove the .project file
  - `gradle cleanEclipseClasspath` to empty the project's classpath
- Finally `gradle eclipse` to rebuild the Eclipse configuration

Comment: This works great. One note, be sure permissions are correct on OSX and Linux. I was running Eclipse as me and gradle as su. That caused Eclipse to not be able to access the config files.

Answer (score 7):

You have to make sure that "Dependency Management" is enabled. To do so, right click on the project name, go to the "Gradle" sub-menu and click on "Enable Dependency Management". Once you do that, Gradle should load all the dependencies for you.

Comment: Eclipse Market place shows that I have gradle integration installed, but I don't see the context menu when I right click on the project! I do have apply plugin: 'eclipse'. any ideas? thanks.

Comment: You Sir, have made my day, thank you. I am baffled on why this is not done automatically, however I did try to add everything manually, must have missed something else.

Comment: If you don't see "Dependency Management" right click on your project, and go to Configure -> Convert to Gradle Project. This enabled dependency management for me. It's weird though because I imported it with the Gradle importer, you would think that it would already BE a Gradle project.

Comment: Does not work in Eclipse Photon. No context menu, and no Configure option either.

Comment: Still the same in eclipse 2020-06: No context menu "Gradle/Dependency Management", and no "Configure/Convert to Gradle project" (but a lot of other "convertTo...").

Answer (score 2):

I tried all above options but was still getting error, in my case issue was I have not setup gradle installation directory in eclipse, following worked:

> eclipse -> Window -> Preferences -> Gradle -> "Select Local
> Installation Directory"
>
> Click on Browse button and provide path.

Even though question is answered, thought to share in case somebody else is facing similar issue.

Cheers !

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I solved weird issues in Spring Tools Suite (essentially Eclipse) after I tried to upgrade Spring Boot and the changes didn't seem to be taking effect.

**Right click on your project -> Gradle -> Refresh Gradle Project**