# Can't get libgdx gdx.pay jar's to download using build.gradle, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: android, eclipse, gradle, libgdx

I am using the libgdx framework which uses gradle, the libgdx setup file created my build.gradle which I haven't had to change any part of until now really. But I am trying to add the `gdx.pay`, `gdx.pay.client`, and `gdx.pay.android` jar's to my project. I added the compiles to my dependencies for each to my core `build.gradle` and did gradle/refresh all which says the build was successful but the jars aren't downloaded to my gradle dependencies, I also tried downloading them and pasting them to the libs folder and then refreshing gradle but that doesn't work either. As far as I've researched my build.gradle file seems to be correct but maybe I'm missing something. My core `build.gradle` is below, I've only really added the lines for the gdx.pay compiles so most of the rest is what the libgdx setup made:

```
    buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
       maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'
        classpath 'org.robovm:robovm-gradle-plugin:1.0.0-beta-01'
    }
}

allprojects {
    apply plugin: "eclipse"
    apply plugin: "idea"

    version = '1.0'
    ext {
        appName = 'my-FF7Squirrelman-game'
        gdxVersion = '1.5.2'
        roboVMVersion = '1.0.0-beta-01'
        box2DLightsVersion = '1.3'
        ashleyVersion = '1.3.1'
        aiVersion = '1.4.0'
    }

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/" }
    }
}

project(":desktop") {
    apply plugin: "java"


    dependencies {
        compile project(":core")
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-lwjgl:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-controllers-desktop:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-controllers-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-tools:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"
    }
}

project(":android") {
    apply plugin: "android"

    configurations { natives }

    dependencies {
        compile project(":core")
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-android:$gdxVersion"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d:$gdxVersion"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-controllers:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-controllers-android:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype:$gdxVersion"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.box2dlights:box2dlights:$box2DLightsVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.ashley:ashley:$ashleyVersion"
       compile "com.badlogicgames.gdxpay:gdx-pay-android:0.9.1"
       compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.8.0"
    }
}

project(":ios") {
    apply plugin: "java"
    apply plugin: "robovm"

    configurations { natives }

    dependencies {
        compile project(":core")
        compile "org.robovm:robovm-rt:${roboVMVersion}"
        compile "org.robovm:robovm-cocoatouch:${roboVMVersion}"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-robovm:$gdxVersion"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-ios"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-ios"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-ios"
    }
}

project(":core") {
    apply plugin: "java"


    dependencies {
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-controllers:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.box2dlights:box2dlights:$box2DLightsVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.ashley:ashley:$ashleyVersion"
       compile "com.badlogicgames.gdxpay:gdx-pay:0.9.1"
       compile "com.badlogicgames.gdxpay:gdx-pay-client:0.9.1"
    }
}

tasks.eclipse.doLast {
    delete ".project"
}
```

Edit: Following the suggestions in the question Enigo linked I tried going to the project location using the command prompt and running "gradle clean", "gradle eclipse", and "gradle cleanEclipse" but it doesn't recognize the gradle command. gradlew works but returns an error:

[image]

and here is the build.gradle located in the android folder which I haven't changed, it's just what the setup created:

```
android {
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"
    compileSdkVersion 21
    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')
    }
}

// needed to add JNI shared libraries to APK when compiling on CLI
tasks.withType(com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageApplication) { pkgTask ->
    pkgTask.jniFolders = new HashSet<File>()
    pkgTask.jniFolders.add(new File(projectDir, 'libs'))
}

// called every time gradle gets executed, takes the native dependencies of
// the natives configuration, and extracts them to the proper libs/ folders
// so they get packed with the APK.
task copyAndroidNatives() { 
    file("libs/armeabi/").mkdirs();
    file("libs/armeabi-v7a/").mkdirs();
    file("libs/x86/").mkdirs();

    configurations.natives.files.each { jar ->
        def outputDir = null
        if(jar.name.endsWith("natives-armeabi-v7a.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/armeabi-v7a")
        if(jar.name.endsWith("natives-armeabi.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/armeabi")
        if(jar.name.endsWith("natives-x86.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/x86")
        if(outputDir != null) {
            copy {
                from zipTree(jar)
                into outputDir
                include "*.so"
            }
        }
    }
}

task run(type: Exec) {
    def path
    def localProperties = project.file("../local.properties")
    if (localProperties.exists()) {
        Properties properties = new Properties()
        localProperties.withInputStream { instr ->
            properties.load(instr)
        }
        def sdkDir = properties.getProperty('sdk.dir')
        if (sdkDir) {
            path = sdkDir
        } else {
            path = "$System.env.ANDROID_HOME"
        }
    } else {
        path = "$System.env.ANDROID_HOME"
    }

    def adb = path + "/platform-tools/adb"
    commandLine "$adb", 'shell', 'am', 'start', '-n', 'com.FF7Squirrelman.game.android/com.FF7Squirrelman.game.android.AndroidLauncher'
}

// sets up the Android Eclipse project, using the old Ant based build.
eclipse {
    // need to specify Java source sets explicitely, SpringSource Gradle Eclipse plugin
    // ignores any nodes added in classpath.file.withXml
    sourceSets {
        main {
            java.srcDirs "src", 'gen'
        }
    }

    jdt {
        sourceCompatibility = 1.6
        targetCompatibility = 1.6
    }

    classpath {
        plusConfigurations += [ project.configurations.compile ]        
        containers 'com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ANDROID_FRAMEWORK', 'com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.LIBRARIES'       
    }

    project {
        name = appName + "-android"
        natures 'com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.AndroidNature'
        buildCommands.clear();
        buildCommand "com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ResourceManagerBuilder"
        buildCommand "com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.PreCompilerBuilder"
        buildCommand "org.eclipse.jdt.core.javabuilder"
        buildCommand "com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ApkBuilder"
    }
}

// sets up the Android Idea project, using the old Ant based build.
idea {
    module {
        sourceDirs += file("src");
        scopes = [ COMPILE: [plus:[project.configurations.compile]]]        

        iml {
            withXml {
                def node = it.asNode()
                def builder = NodeBuilder.newInstance();
                builder.current = node;
                builder.component(name: "FacetManager") {
                    facet(type: "android", name: "Android") {
                        configuration {
                            option(name: "UPDATE_PROPERTY_FILES", value:"true")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

it seems to have an issue with this line "tasks.withType(com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageApplication) { pkgTask ->"

Here is the stacktrace:

```
C:\Users\Joseph\libGDX workspace 2>gradlew clean --stacktrace
Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\Joseph\libGDX workspace 2\android\build.gradle' line: 19

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':android'.
> Could not find property 'com' on project ':android'.

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.GradleScriptException: A problem occurred evaluating project ':an
droid'.
        at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptR
unnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:54)
        at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl.
apply(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:148)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildSc
riptProcessor.java:39)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildSc
riptProcessor.java:26)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.eva
luate(ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.java:34)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(L
ifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:59)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluate(AbstractProj
ect.java:504)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluate(AbstractProj
ect.java:83)
        at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configureHierarchy(Task
PathProjectEvaluator.java:47)
        at org.gradle.execution.TaskSelector.getSelection(TaskSelector.java:85)
        at org.gradle.execution.TaskSelector.getSelection(TaskSelector.java:76)
        at org.gradle.execution.commandline.CommandLineTaskParser.parseTasks(Com
mandLineTaskParser.java:42)
        at org.gradle.execution.TaskNameResolvingBuildConfigurationAction.config
ure(TaskNameResolvingBuildConfigurationAction.java:44)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.configure(DefaultBuildExecu
ter.java:42)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$100(DefaultBuildExec
uter.java:23)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildExecu
ter.java:48)
        at org.gradle.execution.ExcludedTaskFilteringBuildConfigurationAction.co
nfigure(ExcludedTaskFilteringBuildConfigurationAction.java:47)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.configure(DefaultBuildExecu
ter.java:42)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$100(DefaultBuildExec
uter.java:23)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildExecu
ter.java:48)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultTasksBuildExecutionAction.configure(Defau
ltTasksBuildExecutionAction.java:44)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.configure(DefaultBuildExecu
ter.java:42)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.select(DefaultBuildExecuter
.java:35)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(Default
GradleLauncher.java:142)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradle
Launcher.java:106)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLaun
cher.java:86)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildCon
troller.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:80)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.jav
a:33)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.jav
a:24)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProce
ssBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProce
ssBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBu
ild.java:47)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(Build
CommandOnly.java:34)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed
(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(
WatchForDisconnection.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed
(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute
(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:24)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed
(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartStopIfBuildAndStop.execut
e(StartStopIfBuildAndStop.java:33)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed
(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(Forw
ardClientInput.java:71)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(Forw
ardClientInput.java:69)
        at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(For
wardClientInput.java:69)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed
(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClien
t.java:60)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(Build
CommandOnly.java:34)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed
(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBu
ild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:70)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(Build
CommandOnly.java:34)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed
(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonHygieneAction.execute(Da
emonHygieneAction.java:39)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed
(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.
run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:46)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(Daemon
StateCoordinator.java:246)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.DefaultExecutorFactory$StoppableExecut
orImpl$1.run(DefaultExecutorFactory.java:64)
Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: Could not find property 'com' o
n project ':android'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractDynamicObject.propertyMissingExceptio
n(AbstractDynamicObject.java:43)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractDynamicObject.getProperty(AbstractDyn
amicObject.java:35)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.CompositeDynamicObject.getProperty(CompositeD
ynamicObject.java:94)
        at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.BasicScript.propertyMissing(BasicScript.jav
a:66)
        at build_b3vg9nn1m4bfper66jbo5b19l.run(C:\Users\Joseph\libGDX workspace
2\android\build.gradle:19)
        at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptR
unnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:52)
        ... 55 more


BUILD FAILED

Total time: 9.347 secs
```

Comment: Have you tried to select "Refresh Dependencies" in the "Gradle" context menu that appears when you right-click the project in the Package Explorer?

BTW, I tried to compile gdx-pay project in IntelliJ IDEA, and it works like a charm.

Comment: I did refresh all in that same menu which should refresh both but for the sake of testing I did the refresh dependencies option alone as well and it didn't change anything either. Were you using libgdx on your intellij IDEA project? I think it might be the issue since it changes the structure somewhat, though I've seen build files for libgdx apps that were the same.

Comment: Are you using IntelliJ or Eclipse?

Comment: So, the problem is somewhere in eclipse, not with your build.gradle. have you checked this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17907927/5151575) ?

Comment: Did you try running with the `--stactrace` option as the error suggests?

Comment: I edited my post to include the stacktrace as well. Aside from the obvious error it's finding on line 19 I can't tell if anything else is wrong in the stacktrace log.

Comment: try: com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3 and consider updating all your versions to the latest. libgdx 1.5.2 is kinda old. The gdx-pay wiki recommends using libgdx 1.9.1. Maybe create a new blank project /w latest libgdx and copy gradle files and go from there.

Comment: recreating the project and updating (I didn't realize it was that out of date) seems to have fixed it, now I just hoping importing everything from the old file, google play services etc.  are as easy.