# Spring Batch: Cannot recognize ItemProcessor Interface

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch, build.gradle

I am a beginner just started learning Spring Batch. I followed this tutorial [here](http://import%20org.springframework.batch.item.ItemProcessor;) to create a helloworld example. While I was following the tutorial, I encountered a problem when I was trying to import `org.springframework.batch.item.ItemProcessor` into a java class. Hence I searched online and found out that I need to add something inside the build.gradle. The problem was, even though I have added the `org.springframework.batch:spring-batch-core` dependency in build.gradle, I was still having error message for the import. I am using Eclipse Java EE IDE 4.5.0 (Mars) to do this tutorial and have installed the Spring Test Suite (by following the tutorial). I have also tried right clicking the project and choose the "refresh" option but the error message is still there.

Additional note: I have also tried to follow the answer stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17907927/update-my-gradle-dependencies-in-eclipse) but I cannot find the "Refresh Dependencies" in the "Gradle" context menu. How do you even know that the build.gradle is working?

**Below is my code (Java class) that imports the Spring Batch:**

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

//error message: "the import org.springframework.batch cannot be resolved"
import org.springframework.batch.item.ItemProcessor; 


//error message: "ItemProcessor cannot be resolved to a type"
public class PersonItemProcessor implements ItemProcessor<Person, Person> {

    @Override
    public Person process(final Person person) throws Exception {
        //some codes
    }
}
```

**Below is the build.gradle file:**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.3.3.RELEASE")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'

jar {
    baseName = 'gs-consuming-rest'
    version =  '0.1.0'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.batch:spring-batch-core") //added by me
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter")
    compile("org.springframework:spring-web")
    compile("com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind")
    testCompile("junit:junit")
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '2.3'
}
```

Comment: open terminal/cmd, cd into the project directory in which the build.gradle file resides and type "gradle build"

Comment: @neal i have the error " 'gradle' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. "

Comment: I would download the binary from http://gradle.org/gradle-download/ and unzip it into a directory then follow installation instructions here: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/installation.html

Comment: when I installed gradle on my home computer (PC) i had to create a gradle.properties file in the same directory as my gradle.build file and add the following line.  It did not work otherwise:  org.gradle.java.home=C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_40

Comment: @neal Ok. I'm trying to follow the guide in the link that you have provided. I'll update here whether it works or not. Thanks!

Comment: @neal I've tried the user guide but I encountered a "could not find tools.jar error". In the end, I gave up on gradle and straightly downloaded the jar file that contains the library [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.batch/spring-batch-infrastructure/2.2.0.RELEASE) and put it inside the build path. The error message is gone but I wonder if this is a good method

Comment: that stinks.  I'm pretty sure I had to that's why I had "to create a gradle.properties file in the same directory as my gradle.build file and add the following line. It did not work otherwise: org.gradle.java.home=C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_40."  I think gradle was trying to use my JRE rather than my JDK so I had to set the property above in order for it to find the JDK - and tools.jar - which is located in path/to/jdk/libs directory.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with the same tutorial except that I use IntelliJ instead of Eclipse. On IntelliJ there is a "Gradle" panel on the right side that you can open and click refresh. This will refresh your gradle. It solved the problem in my case. (Rebuilding gradle.build didn't)

[image: Red arrow pointing to the gradle panel]

[image: Red arrow pointing to the refresh icon]