# How to build Apache Spark using Gradle?

Tags: java, maven, gradle, apache-spark

I am trying to build an Apache Spark application in Java in Eclipse. I am using Gradle as my build management system. What should I write in my `build.gradle` and which gradle commands should I use to do the same thing which this Maven POM and terminal command does?

```
<project>
  <groupId>edu.berkeley</groupId>
  <artifactId>simple-project</artifactId>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <name>Simple Project</name>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
      <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
      <version>1.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

and

```
mvn package

$ YOUR_SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-submit \
--class "SimpleApp" \
--master local[4] \
target/simple-project-1.0.jar
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this. If it is a Java project, you can remove the first line:

```
apply plugin: 'scala'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies{
    compile "org.apache.spark:spark-core_2.10:1.6.1"
}
```

Comment: This does result in a successful build but in Eclipse the error lines are still appearing for all the imports. The jar is also not created.

Is it possible to do `spark-sumbit` from Gradle?

Comment: To solve that follow these steps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17907927/update-my-gradle-dependencies-in-eclipse, in my case, second answer solved my problem (sorry about my English)

Comment: I don't know if submitting the spark job and building the jar both in Gradle is the best idea @khateeb  I would use jenkins or even better airflow