# How to add a local maven repository as agradle dependency

Tags: spring, maven, gradle

I am new to gradle and I am building a project in it.Now I want to import a maven dependency from local repo into my gradle project .So the path to my local repo is like

`Users/test/.m2/org/springframework/spring-jdbc/4.3.8.RELEASE`

So what I have tried is

```
maven{
       url uri('/Users/test/.m2/repository')
       }
    repositories {
      mavenLocal()
      mavenCentral()


    }
```

and

My **build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '1.5.9.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
group = 'com.smudmmlta.dgs'
version = '1.0'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8
maven{
url uri('/Users/test/.m2/repository')
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
}
dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
    compile('org.springframework.dao')
    compile('com.zaxxer:HikariCP:2.7.6')
    compile('org.mindrot:jbcrypt:0.4')
    compile('org.springframework:spring-jdbc')   
}
```

After this still the program throws error as below:

```
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
```

> The import org.springframework.jdbc cannot be resolved

because of unresolved dependencies.
Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT**
I also changed this part to be like

```
 repositories {
      mavenLocal()
      mavenCentral()
      maven{
       url uri('/Users/test/.m2/repository')
       }

    }
```

Comment: `4.8.3` is hardly `4.3.8`... Also you should be using the `spring-boot-starter-jdbc` instead of manually wanting to add the `spring-jdbc` dependency so that you get the correct version. Also if you really want to use `spring-jdbc` as a dependency as you do now do it **without** the version number. Spring Boot will manage the version for you. (And just use `mavenLocal()` as the repo).

Comment: Is it possible to show the build.gradle file required since I am not getting exactly what are you are saying by Spring Boot will manage the version for you.Thanks

Comment: Just remove the version number from the dependency and use `spring-boot-starter-jdbc` instead of `spring-jdbc`.

Comment: Tried s above but still error is not gone\

Comment: When adking about an error, **post the error**.

Comment: @JB Nizet Updated the question

Comment: The program doesn't throw an error. This is a compilation error. How do you get it? What are you doing to get this error?

Comment: After adding the dependency `compile('org.springframework:spring-jdbc')`   
 and `maven{
url uri('/Users/test/.m2/repository')
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
}` this error shoul get resolved right.But it does not.

Comment: You don't need to add `mavenLocal()`, and even less `maven url ...`. All these dependencies are in maven central. And you didn't answer my question.

Comment: I am not doing any thing to get this error.when I use the class inside the import library  it does not identifies

Comment: Where is this error appearing? In your console? As a response to which command? In your IDE? Which IDE? As a response to which action? Java compilation errors don't appear in front of me when I just look at the blue sky. I need to do something to get them. I bet it's the same for you.

Comment: In my IDE STS .the issue is it doesn't identify the jdbc library .So it could not import the classes from it hence the dependency is unresolved.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17907927/update-my-gradle-dependencies-in-eclipse